# How to turn a iterative DFS into a recursive DFS?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I have written an iterative DFS by implementing a stack. Now I am trying to write the same DFS recursively and I am running into the problems.

My question is, when I write it iteratively, I can keep certain global variables, such as `paths=[]` and I will add into it as I find a new path.

The thing I am confused about the recursive approach is that, there are basically two sets of results that I want to keep track of:

1) Recursively visit nodes to find new paths
2) Each time I find a new path, I want to add that to a list of paths which is then returned.

So my recursive function is now written such that it returns a single path at the base case and it returns a list of paths at the end of the function.

What is a better way to write this?

#### Runnable Python Script here:

https://ideone.com/ekfFDP

#### Code here:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
         'C': ['A', 'F'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['B', 'F'],
         'F': ['C', 'E'],
         'G': ['K']}


def push(array, item):
    array.insert(0, item)

def pop(array):
    return array.pop(0)

def dfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    paths = []
    stack = [(start, [start])]

    while stack:
        (vertex, path) = pop(stack)
        vertices = graph[vertex]

        for next_vertex in (set(vertices) - set(path)):
            new_path = path + [next_vertex]

            if next_vertex == goal:
                paths.append(new_path)
            else:
                push(stack, (next_vertex, new_path))

    return paths

print dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F') # [['A', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F']]

def dfs_paths_rec(graph, start, goal, path=[]):
    if start == goal:
        path.append(start)
        return path

    paths = []
    for next in set(graph[start]) - set(path):
        new_path = dfs_paths_rec(graph, next, goal, path + [next])
        paths.append(new_path)

    return paths

print dfs_paths_rec(graph, 'A', 'F')

# [[[[[['C', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'F']], []]], ['C', 'F', 'F']], [[[['B', 'A', 'C', 'F', 'F']]], [['B', 'E', 'F', 'F']], []]]
```

Comment: Maybe this would be better on [CodeReview?](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @200_success he's asking for a better way to write something though

Comment: @heinst I wasn't aware of code review. Thank you very much for pointing it out

Comment: This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want a _full_ review, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, post it on CR.

Comment: Actually, the recursive code is not working. That's why I am asking how to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def all_paths_dfs(graph, start, end, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    path.append(start)
    all_paths = set()

    if start == end:
        all_paths.add(tuple(path))
    else:
        for neighbor in graph[start]:
            if neighbor not in path:
                all_paths |= all_paths_dfs(graph, neighbor, end, path)

    path.pop()
    return all_paths


if __name__ == "__main__":
    graph = {'A': {'B', 'C'},
             'B': {'A', 'D', 'E'},
             'C': {'A', 'F'},
             'D': {'B'},
             'E': {'B', 'F'},
             'F': {'C', 'E'},
             'G': {'K'}}

    print all_paths_dfs(graph, 'A', 'F')
```

Which returns:

```
set([('A', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'E', 'F')])
```

Comment: This is great. and It works! I am just trying to figure out how this works without a base case! (Clearly I am not good with recursion!)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. On the first call to this function, the path variable is set to an empty list. That list object is then passed into each recursive call. If no path if found from `start` to `end`, then an empty set will be returned.

Comment: NVM, that was a terrible question. Your solution is great!

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the result as a flat list, you want to use [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) instead of `list.append()`.